# Dynamically allocated array C++ reads a sentence and prints the words

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

On the input we get a sentence which we read until EOF. We need to add single words to dynamic array and then write them one on each line.

Input: Hello this, is an example.

Output:

Hello

this,

is

an

example

I have the following code and I can't figure out why it doesn't even add anything to the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void addToArray(string newWord, string myArray[], int& arrayLength)
{
  string * tempArray = new string[arrayLength + 1];
  tempArray[arrayLength] = newWord;

  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
    myArray[i] = tempArray[i];
  }

  arrayLength++;
  myArray = tempArray;

  delete [] tempArray;
}

int main()
{
  string * arrayOfWOrds = new string[1000];
  int arrayLength = 0;
  string temp;

  while (getline(cin, temp))
  {
    cout << temp << endl;
    addToArray(temp, arrayOfWOrds, arrayLength);
  }

  cout << "Array" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
    cout << arrayOfWOrds[i] << endl;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues here. To begin with, you set `arrayLength = 0`,  so it's not going to iterate over the whole array if you have stuff already in it. If you don't have anything in it, there's no point in making it start off with 1000 items. Also, `while (getline(cin,temp))` is an infinite loop, so it will never end and actually print the array. If you want to print the array after each addition, you need to move it into the `while` loop. There's no real reason to `cout` the number the user types either; they can already see the line they just typed.

More importantly, there are real issues with the dynamic allocation. You've created a static array (`string * arrayOfWOrds = new string[1000];`), then you're giving that to the function which makes a new array one item larger, sets the last item in that array to the new value, then iterates over the entire new array and duplicates the values to the old array. Basically, you're just inserting items into the static array at that point, and what you're inserting is a bunch of nothing (because the new array only has one item in it, and it's at arrayLength+1 which is outside the bounds of the original array).

You need to delete the old array, not the new array, which actually should be thrown on the heap and returned.

Basically, it should look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string* addToArray(string newWord, string myArray[], int& arrayLength)
{

  string * returnArray = new string[arrayLength + 1];
  returnArray[arrayLength] = newWord;

  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
    returnArray[i] = myArray[i];
  }
  arrayLength++;
  delete [] myArray;

  return returnArray;
}

int main()
{
  const int startSize = 0;
  string * arrayOfWords = new string[1];
  int arrayLength = startSize;
  string temp;

  cout << "Input: ";
  getline(cin, temp);

  string word = "";
  for (char c : temp){
    if (c == ' '){
      arrayOfWords = addToArray(word, arrayOfWords, arrayLength);
      word = "";
    } else word.push_back(c);
  }
  arrayOfWords = addToArray(word, arrayOfWords, arrayLength); // Don't forget the last word
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
    cout << arrayOfWords[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The only problem is that this always gives me the length of array 1, whereas I would need to split it into words. Any hints on how I could do this?

Comment: My bad, I forgot that part of the question while I was coding the dynamic array. I updated the answer to take multiple words on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't return the new array from the `addToArray` function. The change you make only happens in `addToArray`, it doesn't happen in `main`.

You also `delete[]` the wrong array, you delete the array you've just created.

You also copy the array elements in the wrong direction, i.e. from your new array to your old array.

Try this, I've renamed some of the variables for clarity. There is no temporary array in your function only a new array and an old array. Choosing good variable names is very important for writing working code. Bad variable names just confuse yourself.

```
string* addToArray(string newWord, string* oldArray, int& arrayLength)
{
  string * newArray = new string[arrayLength + 1];
  newArray[arrayLength] = newWord;

  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
  {
    newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
  }

  arrayLength++;

  delete [] oldArray;
  return newArray;
}
```

Then use it like this

```
arrayOfWOrds = addToArray(temp, arrayOfWOrds, arrayLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is unchanged, because you pass the pointer to the `addToArray` function, but it has no way to pass the new pointer back. You can fix this by changing the signature of the function to

`void addToArray(string newWord, string *myArray[], int& arrayLength)`

You also need to change the code accordingly, and fix problem with deallocation.

You can save yourself all the trouble and use `std::vector` in place of manually allocated dynamic array:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<string> arrayOfWOrds;
  string temp;

  while (getline(cin, temp))
  {
    cout << temp << endl;
    arrayOfWOrds.push_back(temp);
  }

  cout << "Array" << endl;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arrayOfWOrds.size(); ++i)
  {
    cout << arrayOfWOrds[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string in="dasd adas ads adsada adsa asd ads",out;
stringstream ss(in);
vector<string> vr;
while(ss>>out)
{
    vr.push_back(out);
    //cout<<out<<endl;
}
for(int i=0;i<vr.length();i++)
{
    cout<<vr[i]<<endl;
}
```

try doing this

Comment: The OP said 'We need to add words to a dynamic array'

Comment: @john I just provided a simple hint(approach) rather than a full working solution which is not the motive of site anyway, moreover its a way better approach than what Op is doing

Comment: The OP is at college, he's practising dynamic arrays. he won't get any marks if he hands in code that doesn't use dynamic arrays.

Comment: OK, i changed my solution may be that better